# scrapy crawl command not running from crontab

Tags: scrapy, cron

here's my script:(test2.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh
echo try1 > run1.txt
cd /home/folder1/folder2
echo try2 > run2.txt
scrapy crawl somepage > /root/sans1.txt
echo try3 > run3.txt
```

here my cron file:

```
00 * * * * cd /root && sh test2.sh >> /root/diggi.log
```

all the files run1.txt,run2.txt,run3.txt and sans1.txt are created.....i m getting thr right output for run1,2,3 but scrapy command doesn't seem to be working as i am getting sans1.txt as an empty file

Comment: What user is the conrtab for? (hopefully not root) What is the output of: `sudo -u mycronuser scrapy version -v`

Comment: What is the output of: `sudo -u root scrapy version -v`

Answer (score 4):

first you need to do `chmod u+x test2.sh`

also include in .sh file path where your scrapy is installed

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
scrapy crawl somepage > /root/sans1.txt
```

then try crontab

```
00 * * * * cd /root && test2.sh >> /root/diggi.log
```

Comment: When I follow this steps this message is being shown: `/bin/sh: script.sh: command not found
`